# Problem with jQuery in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

How create a link_to_remote in a jQuery script where url need a parameter that is a javascript variable.

I need create a link_to_remote in pure jQuery.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i'll help you when we invent telepathy ... meaning we need more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the `:with` parameter with `link_to_remote`:

```
link_to_remote( args[:title], 
                    :update => args[:update],
                    :url => { :action => args[:action], 
                      :id => id, 
                      :starting => args[:starting] 
                    },
                    :with => "'filter[viewer_id]=' + $('filter_viewer_id').value",
                    :loading => "Element.hide('#{args[:update]}');Element.show('#{args[:loading]}')",
                    :complete => "Element.show('#{args[:update]}');Element.hide('#{args[:loading]}')" )
```

Notice how I am sending the filter_viewer_id by getting it's value from a form field with jQuery. If you don't need that level of detail, just pass the name of your javascript variable.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<%= link_to_remote('Hello', :url => "/test?id='+ id +'&test=true") %>
```

This will result in:

```
# => <a href="#" onclick="jQuery.ajax({data:'authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('++FcXPJ0/jfp/IO6sgaEPxMfzOr+vkT5zrGVMMSkJVE='), dataType:'script', type:'post', url:'/test?id='+ id +'&amp;test=true'}); return false;">Hello</a>
```

Comment: OK, My problem is that i have a remote_form so i use a script which make a Ajaxsubmit multipart and convert the data in json. so controller don´t allow render_update. OK? So i need to make page.replace html in complete callback in script tag

Answer (score 0):

Very little info on your post. Are you using Rails 3? If so, did you check the [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) gem out?

Best regards,

-- J. Fernandes